# Ubuntu 10.10: The Update Manager Will Not Authenticate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, ubuntu-10.10

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10. The update manager came up the other day. However, when I hit the "Authenticate" button, nothing happens --- I've let it sit for about 5 min?

Comment: Year of Linux on the desktop, I say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/445303 You have to wait for this bug to be fixed.

For now use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in Terminal ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal )

This simply does the same thing as update manager does - it installs newest versions of the packages on the system. Using the commands above is equivalent to using update manager and does not do upgrades of the system version - if you are on 10.10, it would stay so.

Alternatively you can use **synaptic** to do the updates - press "mark updates" and "apply" toolbar buttons to do the job. More documentation (including an install howto, you will need to `sudo apt-get install synaptic`) here, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

Comment: Upgrade?  So I can't stay with 10.10 and fix this?

Comment: Gryllid, thanks much for the workaround.  Am I write in assuming I just have to wait for an Ubuntu update to fix this?